# Strange module behavior djangoql

Tags: django, django-admin

We use djangoql for easy search in our django admin panel.
The mixin DjangoQLSearchMixin has been added to some of our models in the admin panel.
And sometimes after deployment we get an error in the handler
application_name/model_name/introspect/

Error:

FieldDoesNotExist at /admin/user/user/introspect/
Model_name has no field named 'field_name'

After the reboot, the error disappears. The error cannot be reproduced locally.

Example:
"Address has no field named 'membership_requests'"

```
@admin.register(MembershipRequest, site=admin_site) 
class MembershipRequestAdmin(DjangoQLSearchMixin, admin.ModelAdmin): 
list_display = ("company", "user", "request_type", "status", "created_on", "updated_on")
```

```
class MembershipRequest(PureModelMixin):

    company = models.ForeignKey("constrafor.Company", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="membership_requests")
    user = models.ForeignKey("user.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="membership_requests")
    address = models.OneToOneField(
        "constrafor.Address",
        related_name="membership_requests",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text="FK to constrafor.Address",
    )
    code = models.ForeignKey(
        "constrafor.Code", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="membership_requests", blank=True, null=True
    )
    company_name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1000)
    company_phone = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=15)
    company_type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=Company.COMPANY_TYPE_CHOICES)
    is_needed_email_verification = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=8,
        choices=MembershipRequestStatus.choices,
        default=MembershipRequestStatus.pending,
    )
    request_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=MembershipRequestType.choices,
        default=MembershipRequestType.natural,
    )
```

Comment: Also encountered this, seems to be a heisenbug: it dissappears when you try to study it. Therefore you cannot reproduce it locally. It went away for a while and then came back without any logical reason.

Answer (score 1):

As I remarked in an earlier comment on your question, this seems to be a very tricky heisenbug. Not being able to properly debug it, as it cannot be reproduced, I found a way around it:

```
class CustomDjangoQLSchema(DjangoQLSchema):
    def get_field_instance(self, model, field_name):
        """Some obscure heisenbug caused introspect requests to raise, rendering DjangoQL useless.`

        This catch the exception and just skip the problematic field.
        """
        try:
            return super().get_field_instance(model, field_name)
        except FieldDoesNotExist:
            return None
```

If you use this Schema instead of the default you should be able to skip those failing fields.

**UPDATE:** Later I found out that the model that caused trouble was not registered with Django properly. It makes sense that a model that is not imported in `models.__init__` but that does have a referral causes unexpected behaviour like this.